# make a textfiled without border in material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

i started using material ui for my react today and i want to make a register form like this [one](https://codepen.io/dope/pen/ZQWBeL) basically i just want 5 input text without any border and with a simple background color effect when active my problem is that i couldn't remove all borders of TextField and in the api there is only one css class for the TextFiled component and it don't contain anything about border i tried

```
border:none
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in css:

```
.MuiInputBase-root:before {
  display: none;
}
```

and css for background-colors:

```
.MuiInputBase-root:hover {
  background-color: WHAT_EVER
}
```

Or you can use `customized-inputs` [Follow this](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#customized-inputs)

Comment: aaah ok i checked that the html code and found them it's perfeclty working i can also take off when active but i can't found the hover one when i pass my mouse on it